# Amazon Alexa - Trying to Understanding Alexa Dialogue Flow; Writing conditions for handlers with YesIntent and NoIntent?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently coding in Javascript and new to Amazon Alexa.

I'm trying to write a handler that would end the session after all the questions run out and switch to a different game state.

However, I'm have trouble understanding utterances. Basically what I want to write is:

```
SpeakOutput = "Would you like to keep playing?" // this is where I'm confused where to write this question in the code

if(Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "AMAZON.YesIntent") {
   setGameState(handlerInput, "BiologyQuestions")
            return nextBioQuestion(handlerInput)
} else {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(" That was fun! Let's play together next time! ")
                .withShouldEndSession(true)
                .getResponse();
}
```

In plain English it would be:

Alexa: * finishes all the questions in the Literature Questions Round * Would you like to keep playing?

User: Yes!

Alexa: * Switches to Biology Questions *

Should I write another helper function to carry out that question? I already have coded the "nextBioSession" function. I guess I have a hard time really understanding how to write the conditions to enable the "Would you like to keep playing?" question and have it be answered.

This is what I currently have as a code:

```
const QuestionCheckHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest"
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "AMAZON.YesIntent" || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "AMAZON.NoIntent")
            && handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes().gameState === "LiteratureQuestions";
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        if(Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "AMAZON.YesIntent") {
            setGameState(handlerInput, "BiologyQuestions")
            return nextBiologyQuestion(handlerInput)
        } else {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(" That was fun. Let's play together next time! ")
                .withShouldEndSession(true)
                .getResponse();
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure where to code the SpeakOutput "Would you like to continue?" either before the condition or as a separate helper function... I have tried to put the question before the condition but it seems like it's not recognizing it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you store the game state somewhere so you know how many questions are left in the round. After user's last answer in the Literature Questions Round just add your question to Alexa response.